# How the number of function arguments affects performance

Tags: function, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

When coding a function, I usually recall the "Clean Code" principle of

> A function shouldn’t have more than 3 arguments.

However, given these x86-64 calling conventions below, I've relaxed it to 4 arguments because that covers cross-platform functions by ensuring that CPU registers are utilized versus stack operations which are slower than register access.

**System V AMD64 ABI**

```
Integer/Pointer Arguments 1-6:  RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9
Floating Point Arguments 1-8:   XMM0 - XMM7
Excess Arguments:               Stack
```

**Microsoft x64 calling convention**

```
Integer/Pointer Arguments 1-4:  RCX, RDX, R8, R9
Floating Point Arguments 1-4:   XMM0 - XMM3
Excess Arguments:               Stack
```

**Example**

Limiting the number of arguments to 4, ensures both Windows and Linux use registers instead of the stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Add(int a, int b, int c, int d) { return a + b + c + d; }

int main() {
    int sum = Add(1,2,3,4);
    return 0;
}
```

**Linux Disassembly**

```
mov     ecx, 4
mov     edx, 3
mov     esi, 2
mov     edi, 1
call    Add
```

**Windows Disassembly**

```
mov     r9d,4  
mov     r8d,3  
mov     edx,2  
mov     ecx,1  
call    Add
```

**Question**

When writing cross-platform functions, is this micro-optimization a viable new mantra?

> A function shouldn’t have more than 4 arguments.

**Note**

Specific use case is assembling code with [UASM](https://www.terraspace.co.uk/uasm.html) (understands MASM syntax) on windows and linux.

For compilers (msvc, gcc), optimizer tools would handle performance, however, for assemblers (masm, nasm, uasm) there are no such tools.

The 4 args mantra was chosen for performance (not a coding style) so that the generated code started from an optimized state.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think it's a big concern. It is my understanding that modern processors optimize access to the immediate stack frame, so the difference in performance between register and stack-based arguments is not nearly what it used to be.

Comment: I strongly recommend not making such decisions based on calling convention.    In practice, the perf difference is tiny and likely overshadowed by other factors.  Program without dogma such that your code is easy to understand.

Comment: If you need to add 4 values as in the example, then use 4 arguments. Do you suppose that calling a 2-argument function three times will be cheaper? `int sum = Add(Add(1, 2), Add(3, 4));`

Comment: I suspect the person making that "clean code" pronouncement works with high level languages where those 3 arguments might be objects or structs with multiple member variables.

Comment: It depends on how often the function is called too. There are no hard rules, but if many of your functions take a lot of arguments it might be good to review the code structure.

Comment: Passing extra arguments is almost always cheaper than whatever method you use to work around the parameter limit you impose. If your function needs more than 4 arguments, use more than 4 arguments! The stack is almost always in L1 cache (which is the second fastest storage after registers).

Comment: I know you're showing a contrived example, but with optimization, the compiler would have inlined those function calls.

Comment: Your proposed "mantra" is only relevant to the very specific situation you are in: coding in assembly, for x86-64, with code that must work on two specific platforms.  But you've framed it as if it ought to be some universal rule, which seems very misleading.  The general principle is about coding *style* and should be independent of platform or language, and in any case is only a very rough and subjective rule of thumb.

Comment: @ErikEidt Any sane optimizing compiler generates the following assembly for `main`: `xor eax, eax`, `ret`

Comment: @DarkAtom, yes, after inlining, further optimization follows.

Comment: @ErikEidt I'm not very familiar with the wonders of compiler optimization...but wouldn't it be more efficient to first see that the function has no side effects and that the results of the function call are never used? Why go through all the trouble of inlining a function which will end up as dead code anyway?

Comment: @DarkAtom, inlining is the likely approach by which those things are discovered (lack of side effects).  A different approach as you suggest could certainly be used, though. The methodical approach of inlining first, then applying further optimization might actually be slower for exceptionally useless sample code, but most code has useful purpose, and this approach is designed to work for that; it will still eventually get to that return 0 result here though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "clean code" principle you're talking about most likely refers to exactly that: code tidiness and readability. Many parameters usually means long lines and/or parameter lists broken into multiple lines (just look at Win32 functions with 10 arguments).

However, since it seems that you are asking this from a strictly performance perspective, it doesn't matter how many parameters a function has. Rather than reducing the number of **arguments**, you should try to reduce the number of **calls**. A good way to do this is to write reasonably short functions which the compiler can inline.

Let's suppose that instead of 4 numbers, my code needs to add a batch of 4 and a batch of 5. With a 4 parameter function, I will need to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Add(int a, int b, int c, int d) { return a + b + c + d; }

int main() {
    int sum1 = Add(1,2,3,4);
    int sum2 = Add(1,2,3,Add(4,5,0,0));
    return 0;
}
```

Now let's say I use a 5-parameter function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Add(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) { return a + b + c + d + e; }

int main() {
    int sum1 = Add(1,2,3,4,0);
    int sum2 = Add(1,2,3,4,5);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the second version only uses 2 calls (because I need 2 different sums). The first version used 3 calls. So you're trading 4 `mov` stack accesses (in the 5-arg version) for a whole extra `call`/`ret` pair. Which, mind you, also make 2 stack accesses for the return address (while possibly also introducing additional overhead in the form of shadow stack accesses, canary values placed in the new function's stack frame etc).

Of course, this example uses an `Add` function which is inlined by the compiler (actually, it's not, the compiler detects that the sum is not needed and the `Add` function has no additional side effects and generates an empty `main`). But with a realistic function that's more complex it will almost always be better to call it fewer times.

This is, however, just the tip of the iceberg when it comes to performance. If you worry about performance, get a profiler and find the bottlenecks in your code. If your code is slow in a badly written loop you should only optimize that by hand. Leave most of the optimization to the compiler itself, because it knows what it's doing and has been refined for decades.

Your requirements are also somewhat contradictory. You are *writing **cross-platform** functions* but also the *Specific use case is **assembling code with UASM***?